# Cannot access folders created with rsync

Tags: rsync, cygwin

I am using rysnc via Cygwin on Windows 7 Professional.

```
$ rsync -version
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
```

I am trying to set up a backup using rsync to a USB drive.

I ran the following command:

```
rsync -v -rplt "/cygdrive/k/Email/" "/cygdrive/d/Backup Files/k/"
```

[ I got the same result with "-rlt" flags, I added the "p" flag to instruct rsync to copy the persmissions"].

This seems to work fine, however when I try to look at the results I get permission denied messages:

```
$ ls /cygdrive/d/Backup\ Files/k
ls: cannot open directory '/cygdrive/d/Backup Files/k': Permission denied
```

I cannot access via Windows Explorer either.

If I unplug the USB drive and connect to another PC I can see the files.

Comment: Hello TenG. What filesystem is being used on the K: drive? What filesystem is being used on the USB D: drive? (FAT32? NTFS? REFS? Something else?) Is the K: drive local or remote? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/365032/edit) to provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have "chattr" enabled for the folder/file/contents of the USB storage

Try to first execute this :

```
chattr -R -ai <folder>
```

or

```
 chattr -R -ai <files>
```

and then do rsync and ls command to check if it gives a permission denied message.